# How to eval a string containing column names?

Tags: vba, eval, ms-access-2016

As I cannot attach a conditional formatting on a Table, I need an abstract function to chech if a set of records or all records have errors inside, and show these errors into forms and/or reports.

Because, to achieve this goal in the 'standard' mode, I have to define the rule [○for a field of a table every time I use that field  in a control or report, and this means the need to repeate the same things an annoying lot of times, not to tell about introducing errors and resulting in a maintenance nightmare.

So, my idea is to define all the check  for all the tables and their rows in an CheckError-table, like the following fragment related to the table 'Persone':

```
TableName |      FieldName   |   TestNumber   |   TestCode                                    |   TestMessage                              |   ErrorType[/B][/COLOR]
Persone   | CAP              |       4        | len([CAP]) = 0 or isnull([cap])               | CAP mancante                               | warning
Persone   | Codice Fiscale   |       1        | len([Codice Fiscale]) < 16                    | Codice fiscale nullo o mancante            | error
Persone   | Data di nascita  |       2        | (now() - [Data di nascita]) < 18 * 365        | Minorenne                                  | info
Persone   | mail             |       5        | len([mail)] = 0 or isnull([mail]              | email mancante                             | warning
Persone   | mail             |       6        | (len([mail)] = 0 or isnull([mail])            | richiesto l'invio dei referti via e- mail, | error
          |                  |                |  and [modalità ritiro referti] = ""e-mail""   | ma l'indirizzo e-mail è mancante           |         
Persone   | Via              |       3        | len([Via]) = 0 or isnull([Via])               | Indirizzo mancante                         | warning
```

Now, in each form or report which use the table Persona, I want to set an 'onload' property to a function

```
' to validate all fields in all rows and set the appropriate bg and fg color
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)      
    Call validazione.validazione(Form, "Persone", 0)
End Sub

' to validate all fields in the row identified by ID and set the appropriate bg and fg color
Private Sub Codice_Fiscale_LostFocus()
  Call validazione.validazione(Form, "Persone", ID)
End Sub
```

So, the function validazione, at a certain point, as exactly one row for the table Persone, and the set of expressions described in the column [TestCode] above.

Now, I need to logically evaluate the TestString against the table row, to obtain a true or a false.

If true, I'll set the fg and bg color of the field as normal
if false, I'll set the the fg and bg color as per error, info or warning, as defined by the column [ErrorType] above.

---

All the above is easy, ready, and running, except for the red statement above:

How can I evaluate the teststring against the table row, to obtain a result?

Thank you

Paolo

Comment: Each row in table T might have a different length for its code characters.  e.g. 2019Q1 or 20190310 or 2019M03.  What is the expected output?  The max length of the column in the table? Or the length of the value in a particular row?  It the column type ShortText? LongText? Number? etc...  with default lengths or custom length?

Comment: I'm trying to build an abstract tester function, where there is a file containing, for any table and fields in a row, all the rules to be satisfied as the row is correct.

Some rules are complex, as '(now() - [birthdate]) > 18 * 365' is used to info that the person is 18 yo or lower, and, as exemple he/she can vote.

Comment: Please supply sample FORM and indicate where each of the errors is to be placed.  Ditto for REPORT.  When dealing with one row from Persone table, then there might be an ability to use the Form.Objects that relate to each of the rst.Fields.  But when dealing with a Form.Datasheet or a Report the objects are the columns and not the fields; thus indicating which row/column has a specific error is not possible without additional "Error-CAP/-Codice/..." text boxes... So, show us the design of the Form(s) and Report(s) so we can see what the expected results are to look like.

Comment: I closed this thread and opened a new one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733649/how-to-set-conditional-formatting-for-forms-reports-and-datasheet-using-vba